# Scrapy won't recognize txt file in the same directory

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, io, scrapy

Trying to write, and then read data from Scrapy onto a .txt file.  Here's the `parse()` code for my crawler.

```
def parse(self, response):
    lastpage = response.xpath("/ol[@class='pagination']/li[7]/a/text()").extract()
    with open('num_pages.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(lastpage)
```

This code doesn't throw an error, but later trying to read the same file does.

```
num_pages = int(open('num_pages.txt', 'r').strip())
```

Even though there is clearly a num_pages.txt in the same directory as the spider, running the crawler gives the error message

> No such file or directory: 'num_pages.txt.'

Furthermore, even though the write isn't throwing an error, the num_pages.txt is empty when I manually open it.  Is there something I'm doing wrong with the file i/o?  Thanks!

Comment: The first error makes me wonder if after calling `parse(response)` if you are not changing directories. Or else perhaps parse is not finished yet. The second makes me wonder if you have any data in your response.

Comment: it could depend from where you are running `scrapy`, maybe set the entire path.

Comment: Add 'num_pages.txt' to root directory of your scrapy project. It will work